# How to stream hls v4/v5 encoded to Chromecast?

Tags: swift, chromecast, google-cast

I'm facing an issue to cast my video url to Chromecast

I can't play this video

http://cdnlb.tvplayhome.lt/vod/eds/220830_test1/220830_test1/_/hls_v4/220830_test1.m3u8

but if I switch to hls_v3 or 2 or 1 it is playing

http://cdnlb.tvplayhome.lt/vod/eds/220830_test1/220830_test1/_/hls_v3/220830_test1.m3u8

This is the basic implementation

```
            let url = URL.init(string: "http://cdnlb.tvplayhome.lt/vod/eds/220830_test1/220830_test1/_/hls_v4/220830_test1.m3u8")
        guard let mediaURL = url else {
            print("invalid mediaURL")
            return
        }

        let mediaInfoBuilder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder.init(contentURL: mediaURL)
        mediaInfoBuilder.streamType = GCKMediaStreamType.none;
        mediaInfoBuilder.contentType = "application/x-mpegURL"
        mediaInfoBuilder.metadata = metadata
        mediaInfoBuilder.mediaTracks = nil
        let mediaInformation = mediaInfoBuilder.build()

        let rmc = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient


        let request = rmc?.loadMedia(mediaInformation)
        request!.delegate = self
```

and I'm getting this in the console

```
cast connected
-[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:] - Received unexpected error: Invalid Request.
-[GCKMediaQueue request:didFailWithError:] - error fetching queue item IDs: Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=4 "Invalid request" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid request}
```

Comment: May be the problem is in the encoding of the video, but I don't know what it is exactly. We switched to DASH :) I'll leave the question unanswered because I'm not sure what exactly was the problem...